# Difference between result of character and integer pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

I was trying to execute the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int arr[4] = {1,2,3,4};
    int *p;
    p = arr;
    cout << "p=" << p << endl;

    char ch3[4] = {'c','d','e'};
    char *ptr;
    ptr = ch3;
    cout << ptr << endl;
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

When I print the pointer p, it prints the address of the array 'arr' which is stored in it, whereas when I print the pointer ptr, it prints the array ch3 and not the address of it.
I wanted to know why is this happening.

Comment: You need to cast the pointer to void* to see the value of pointer

Answer (score 7):

Because `operator<<` is overloaded for `const char*` - that overload prints the char array located at that address.

To see the address itself, you'll need to cast it to `void*`:

```
cout<<static_cast<void*>(ptr)<<endl;
```

Comment: It doesn't *just* print the char array; it prints the C-style *string*, which must be terminated with a null character `'\0'`. The `ch3` array happens to have a null terminator, because the initializer only specifies the first 3 elements, and the last one defaults to 0. If there is no null terminator, the behavior is undefined.